# Convert any date specified in a form submission to a given format

Tags: c#, html, datetime, datepicker

We currently have a bit of a dilemma with some search functionality we are setting up for a client specifically when it comes to dates and globalization.

In our search form, we allow the user to specify a date. On browsers that support it, such as Chrome, the date will be input using a HTML5 date-picker so that we are not using any unnecessary JavaScript. In those that do not, we will use a JavaScript solution such as the jQuery date-picker.

In the case of the jQuery date-picker, we can specify the format of the date before it is posted to the page that processes our form post. So if we always want the date to come across as dd/MM/yyyy we can do that. With the browser date-picker, this is outside of our control as I believe the date format is then determined by the language of the machine that is being used.

The dates that we will be searching against in our database are in the format dd/MM/yyyy so this is the format we would like the dates from our form to be converted to.

We have tried using the DateTime.Parse option in C# but this poses a number of issues.

Please see the code below:

```
/* Posted Data */
string difficulty = Request["tripDifficulty"];
string type = Request["tripType"];
string duration = Request["tripDuration"];
string startDate = Request["dateFrom"];
string endDate = Request["dateTo"];

string locale = Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].Split(new char[] { ',' })[0];

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(locale);

DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(startDate, ci);
DateTime dateTo = DateTime.Parse(endDate, ci);

List<string> dates = new List<string>();

for (DateTime dt = dateFrom; dt <= dateTo; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
    string date = dt.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dates.Add(date);
}
```

In our current implementation of the code, we are using the request headers of the browser to retrieve the first item in the accept-language header. So, this will return something like [en-GB, en-US, fr-FR etc]. We then use this to define the current culture information on our Razor page before attempting to parse the dates sent from the form into the format of given culture.

We then use the two dates specified to create a range of dates so that we can search all of the departures in our database between the two dates specified.

In our database the dates will simply be stored in dd/MM/yyyy format so regardless of what format comes from the form, we always need to convert the input into this format.

The issue we have with the above setup is in the case where we use Javascript the input will be fixed to dd/MM/yyyy but this may not comply with the language on the users machine meaning the accept-language header will be different and the DateTime.Parse will not work.

Therefore I need a way of ensuring that the dates from my form whether they be selected via a browser datepicker, a jQuery datepicker or entered in a text field that is validated to a certain format are the same as the format in my database either when they are sent to my razor page that does the processing or are converted to the required format at the start of the razor page.

Does anyone have any ideas of the best way to approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you simply populate a hidden field for time format when using the javascript picker so you can override the culture when that input method is used?

Answer (score 0):

Try [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) with [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example

```
string someDate = "12/30/2015";
string[] formats = { "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy" };
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(someDate, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
String.Format("{0:dd/mm/yyyy}", date);
```

**UPDATE:** If you have a date that uses '.' or '-' as separator you can use a foreach loop to replace these with a '/'.
Like this:

```
string someDate = "12.30.2015";
string newDate = "";
foreach (char c in someDate)
{
    if (c == '.' || c == '-')
    {
        newDate += '/';
    }
    else
    {
        newDate += c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This means I can specify the most common date formats (MM/dd/yyyy, dd/MM/yyyy, yyyy/MM/dd) and then error out the form if none of these are present.

Comment: However, there is a problem as this does not cater for countries that use (.) or - as a date seperator